# Android webview got NullPointerException in sendViewSizeZoom()

Tags: android

I have added Crashlytics in my app, and I got lots of exception like following call stack.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.sendViewSizeZoom(WebViewClassic.java:4012)
       at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.setFrame(WebViewClassic.java:7470)
       at android.webkit.WebView.setFrame(WebView.java:2111)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14053)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1644)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1428)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

There are lots of WebView used in my app, I don't know which activity got this exception throw call stack. The crashed device is Samsung Galaxy S3.

I have searched Google and this forum with keywords "sendViewSizeZoom and NullPointerException", but I can not find any clue.

Does any one know why this issue happened? or How to trace these kinds of issue? 
Please kindly help, thank you.

Comment: can you please update your code without code we are not able to help you.

Comment: Your stacktrace doesn't contain reference to the place in your code (it should start with your package name) that raised this exception. Also, provide the steps that cause this crash.

Comment: There is no such issue happend when my teammate and I do the test. I know this issue through the tool "Crashlytics". There are lots of activity with webview in my app (more than 50 activity). I don't know which webview of activity cause this issue happened. I do not know how this issue happend, so I can not tell the reproduce step. I also do not know which Activity cause this crash, so I do not know which source code of my app to paste.

Comment: I have tried to check the WebViewClassic source in AOSP and I found that the crashed line number in call stack is not the same as AOSP source code. I think Samsung customized the WebViewClassic source. According to the crash call stack, it seems happend when app doing layout. That is the hardest part to track, cause layout is scheduled by Android. When scheduled job occur error, I do not know how to find the root cause.  I think Maybe there is someone got the same issue before and knows what is going on or how to fix it. Or someone know how to track scheduled and crashed issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think this happens when you exit an activity and the webview hasn't finished loading its page...
so add a flag if it has finished or not an then finish/exit activity